# ¿Como traer datos sin registro en una consulta sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

En una consulta `sql` quisiera traer los usuarios que no estan registrados en un grupo definido, **EJEMPLO:**

Tengo 10 usuarios registrados en mi base de datos, pero de esos 10 hay 5 registrados en el `GRUPO1`, la idea es mostrar los otros 5 que no estan registrados en ese grupo.

Tengo la siguiente consulta, pero no me muestra ningún resultado.

```
SELECT
users.userId,
users.userName,
users.userEmail
FROM
users
WHERE users.userId NOT IN 
(SELECT
usergroup.userGroupId,
usergroup.userGroup_groupId,
usergroup.userGroup_userId
FROM
usergroup
WHERE usergroup.userGroup_groupId = 1)
```

Comment: El ID de usuario y el ID de grupo no son la misma cosa. ¿Tienes un campo userID en `usergroup` o un campo `groupID` en `users`?

Comment: No, el id del usuario y el id del grupo son distintos, ya editare la subconsulta para que veais los campos en la tabla grupo, pues la tabla userGroup es una tabla detalle (intermedia).

Comment: La subconsulta solo debiera retornar  `userGroup_userId` para que funcione el `NOT IN`, salvo eso no veo nada mal en tu consulta.

Comment: @amenadiel en su anterior comentario, te comentaba que estabas utilizando el campo `userGroup_groupId` como campo devuelto por tu subconsulta en lugar de devolver `userGroup_userId`. Es decir.. `(SELECT userGroup_userId FROM...`

Comment: @DavidIsla, Así es, quizás no lo había entendido, pero me ha funcionado, muchísimas gracias por la colaboración.

Answer (score 1):

Viendo la pregunta editada, y que la tabla `usergroup` tiene los id de usuario:
esto funcionaría:

```
SELECT
  users.userId,
  users.userName,
  users.userEmail
FROM users
WHERE users.userId NOT IN 
( SELECT usergroup.userGroup_userId
  FROM usergroup
  WHERE usergroup.userGroup_groupId = 1
) ug
```

Aunque sería más eficiente usar:

```
SELECT
  u.userId,
  u.userName,
  u.userEmail
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN  usergroup ug ON u.userId = ug.userGroup_userId AND ug.userGroup_groupId = 1
WHERE ug.userGroup_userId IS NULL
```

Comment: Me parece importante aclarar que eventualmente la segunda consulta podría fallar si un mismo usuario estuviera en dos grupos distintos. Sería mejor si el `LEFT` se hiciera sobre la subconsulta de la primer opción. Saludos.

Comment: Pero al incluir un AND al ON estoy haciendo left join sólo a los usuarios del grupo 1

Comment: Es cierto, mala mía. Descarta mi comentario.

Answer (score 1):

En teoría si tiene usuarios y grupos, hay una posible falla de diseño, dependiendo de lo siguiente:
- Si un usuario puede estar en mas de un grupo y grupo puede tener mas de un usuario, en realidad es una relación muchos a muchos que requiere una tabla que las una, por ejemplo, usuarios_grupos, donde se herede la llave primaria de cada uno de ellos y se generen relaciones 1:N y N:1, mas las columnas que se deseen.

El esquema mencionado anteriormente comúnmente aplica en ejemplos de escuelas, donde se cuenta con alumnos, materias, salones, profesores, etc, y cada tabla de las mencionadas genera relaciones N:N y es necesario convertirlas en relaciones 1:N y/o N:1 y de forma natural se puede sacar la información sin problema

Tabla users:
  userId (Pk),
  u.userName,
  u.userEmail
  ... Otras columnas

Tabla groups:
  groupId (Pk),
  descripcion
  ... Otras columnas

Tabla grups_users (rompe relaciones N:N)
  user.userId (Fk)
  group.groupId /Fk)
  ... Otras columnas

De ésta forma queda normalizado el diseño entidad-relación y las consultas son mas sencillas

Select us.userId (Pk), us.userName, us.userEmail
From   users us, groups_users gu
Where  gu.groupId != 1

Espero ésto ayude.

Saludos!!!

Comment: Saludos @Hugo, muchas gracias por tu aporte, y reconozco que has invertido de tu tiempo para aportar a el problema que tenia anteriormente, y como ves, tengo una tabla que se llama usergroup la cual seria la tabla (como yo le llamo "detalle") intermedia, entre el usuario (users) y el grupo (group)...
De igual manera creo que tienes un problema y es el siguiente, no podrias hacer una diferencia (!=) independiente del id del grupo que sea..

Comment: puesto que si el usuario 1 esta en el grupo 2 y en el grupo 3 por ejemplo, la condicion del grupo no se estaria cumpliendo. ya que se requiere que un usuario no este en un grupo definido, que en este caso es el 1, de igual manera tu teoria es 100% valida y veridica.